# Can Mono's / Flux's be re-used / are they immutable + stateless?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

From my understanding, Mono's and Flux's are "immutable" in Reactive Programming.

Does this mean if I have 2 identical operations to run (for example the same Mono definition), is it proper to just reuse the same definition.

In a way treating these 2 objects (Mono and Flux) as sets of instructions instead instructions **with** current state.

For example:

```
 Mono<String> someMono = // Some Custom Mono

 //Perform 2 concurrent someMono calls , and block on result
 Mono.zip(someMono, someMono, (a,b) -> a + b).block();
```

Is this valid  / best-practice Reactive Code?

Comment: I tried and tried and still don’t quite know what you are asking. You can try all that for yourself. Are you asking whether you can rely on the results of your attempts, or whether those are just artifacts of your specific implementation that may differ with another?

Comment: High level .. should they be treated like Anonymous Functions (~ definition of work / instruction) or Futures / Stream in Java (which also include the state of work).

Comment: In your code example, exactly where are your reactive objects being "reused"?

Comment: `someMono` is used twice (in the `zip` function). If thas Mono is defined using some `Supplier` or `Callable`, it will be executed twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Project Reactor information:

> Project Reactor streams are also reusable, which is a significant
>   difference from Java 8 Streams.

https://stackify.com/reactive-spring-5/

.. so the answer is yes, they are meant to be reusable as opposed to something like a Java Stream, Future, etc

Comment: However, _‘meant to be’_ is not good enough. Consider a Flux created by `Flux.fromStream(Stream.of("F", "G", "H"))` which can be consumed exactly once because of the semantics of the embedded Java stream.